# Regex: find all strings which include at least 3 numeric chars and that there's at least one space between them, how can it be done?

Tags: regex

I have a regex that matches strings with alphanumeric chars which are 12 chars and longer:

`/\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{12,}).*\d+.*\b/g`

I want it to return matches with only more than 2 digits and at least one of them must be separated than the other 2.

Examples:

```
abcdefghijk9lmn8 - no match
abcdefghijklmn987 - no match
abcdefg9hijklmn87 - match
abcdefg9hijkl8mn7 - match
```

Can you please help me with that regex?

Comment: Your regex matches words, not strings. You must have meant `^` and `$` instead of the `\b`s?

Comment: Try [`/\b(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d){3})(?=.*\d[a-zA-Z]+\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{12,}\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/k1ODOu/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with 2 lookaheads:

```
^(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d){3})(?=.*\d[a-zA-Z]+\d)[0-9A-Za-z]{12,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QxKQUA/9)

- `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d){3})` - Lookahead to assert at least 3 digits in input
- `(?=.*\d[a-zA-Z]+\d)` - Lookahead to assert that at least 2 digits have an alphabet in between